# How to find/refresh local network SAMBA Shares on a Linux computer with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, samba

I am writing a c++ program on a Linux (KDE) computer that accesses files on a SAMBA share in a local network. However, I’m finding that if the ip address lease expires the connection to the SAMBA share is lost.

If I type “smb://sharename” into the address bar of Dolphin, it causes the system to renew the ip address and my connection can be resumed.

My question is – what c or c++ functions can I call to provide the same outcome as Dolphin?

Comment: What is Dolphin in this context?

Comment: Dolphin in this context is KDE's version of Windows Explorer.

Comment: By “smb://sharename” you mean  “smb://server/sharename”? And why can't you use the server hostname in your program instead of the explicit IP?